Nodejs socket.io connection with azure app service
I'm encountering issues connecting to a Socket.IO server deployed on an Azure Web App. Here's an overview of my setup and the problem I'm facing:
Setup:
I have a Node.js application deployed to an Azure Web App.
The application includes a Socket.IO server configured to listen on a custom port (8444).
I've set up CORS to allow connections from specific domains.
The server code looks like this:
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);

const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  serveClient: false,
  path: '/api/socket/',
  cors: {
    origin: [
      'http://localhost:3000',

    ]
  },
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 8444;

httpServer.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Socket.IO server listening on port ${port}`);
});

Problem:
Despite the server running without errors, I'm unable to establish a WebSocket connection from my client application.
I've tried various troubleshooting steps, including checking network configurations and ensuring that the port is accessible, but I haven't been able to resolve the issue.
Any suggestions or insights into what might be causing the problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

If possible,can you share your github repo?

I tried deploying a Node.js App with Socket.IO to Azure app service(linux) without any issues. This is my project structure:
node_modules/
public/
  └── index.html
package-lock.json
package.json
server.js

I made few changes to your server.js file
I removed these lines from your code and was able to get a successful output:
serveClient: false,
  path: '/api/socket/',

These options are used to customize how Socket.IO serves its client library and sets the path for the WebSocket connection. However, they are optional, and if they are causing problems, we can remove them.
This is the modified Server.js:
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');
const path = require('path'); 
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: [
      'http://localhost:3000',
    ]
  }
});
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8445; 
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'));
});
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('A user connected');
  socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
    console.log('message: ' + msg);

    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('User disconnected');
  });
});
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Socket.IO server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});

This is my index.html:
<!DOCTYPE  html>
<html  lang="en">
<head>
<meta  charset="UTF-8">
<meta  name="viewport"  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Socket.IO Chat</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul  id="messages"></ul>
<form  id="form"  action=""
<input  id="input"  autocomplete="off"  /><button>Send</button>
</form>
<script  src="http://localhost:8445/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var  socket = io();
var  form = document.getElementById('form');
var  input = document.getElementById('input');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
if (input.value) {
socket.emit('chat message', input.value);
input.value = '';
}
});
socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
var  item = document.createElement('li');
item.textContent = msg;
document.getElementById('messages').appendChild(item);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>

Local output:


Here's the output after Deployment:


Have you deployed on azure linux machine? My issue is with azure web app deployed on linux machine

Yeah deployed on Azure app service (linux)

I basically have two apps, one is azure static web app where I have deployed my React application, and the other server side node app, deployed on azure app service linux.
On client side I am using socket.io client library.
On connection the app is giving error:
WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

Got it resolved by degrading the socket io package version on my react app.
